# How to get the install directory from registryusing win32 API

Tags: winapi, firefox, registry

I am using `RegOpenKeyEx()` and giving registry path `Software\\Mozilla\\Mozilla Firefox` ,its giving `error_sucess`.

But after that how can I get the install directory `Data` of Mozilla Firefox from that path using `RegQueryValueEx()`?

Answer (score 2):

First you need to open Software\Mozilla\Mozilla Firefox and query the CurrentVersion value for the current active version.

Then, open Software\Mozilla\Mozilla Firefox\\Main and query its Install Directory value.

RegQueryValueEx is used like so;

```
TCHAR buffer[1024] = {0};
DWORD bufferSize = sizeof(buffer);
DWORD result = RegQueryValueEx( hkeyMain,
                         TEXT("Install Directory"),
                         NULL,
                         NULL,
                         (LPBYTE)buffer,
                         &bufferSize);
if (result == ERROR_SUCCESS)
{
    // buffer now contains the install directory
}
```

Comment: can u pls give example code for fetch the curect version value .because now facing problem for curect version and getting "access denied", RegQueryValueEx(hKey,L"CurrentVersion",NULL,/*REG_SZ*/NULL,(LPBYTE)version,&len);

Comment: @BhrKamal: Access denied should only happen on RegOpenKeyEx -- can you show what you are doing in that call?

Comment: You should mention that once you get the current version (e.g. "10.0 (en-US)"), you must append that to the path of the registry key, such that the "Install Directory" value is actually in the subkey "HKLM\Software\Mozilla\Mozilla Firefox\10.0 (en-US)\Main".